# watir-webdriver - verify_contains does not appear to be supported

Tags: firefox, watir-webdriver

I am in the process of converting my existing test scripts that function fine on Firefox 3.6 to work on firefox 4.0. I've noticed a significant number of syntax changes but the one that is plaguing me at the moment is using verify_contains('text').

The same test that functions fine on firefox 3.6 throws the following error on firefox 4.0 when I use the watir-webdriver

test_060contactmgmt(Test_contact_mgmt):
NoMethodError: undefined method `verify_contains' for #.

If this helps any, I ran a gem update and I am using Netbeans IDE 6.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that method has been deprecated in watir-webdriver; for more information have a look at this page [Comparison with Watir 1.X](https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/wiki/Comparison-with-Watir-1.X) at GitHub for the project.

You could always extend the class in your own code to include your own version of the method, I have done this to cover some of the missing methods in my test script after converting them from Watir.